# create our own frame work in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks

There are lots of the frameworks available for different purposes, but I want to create framework library for my some of my classes -- in that all the .m files are loaded in single .a file and it's used with the list of header files.

Can any one tell me how to create a framework?

Comment: You seem to know basically how to do it (create a .a and have a list of headers) -- what part are you having a problem with?

Comment: The key to a good framework is documentation.  If you paste the header file to your framework, we can provide help with naming convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a "Cocoa Touch Static Library" project in Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

This webpage should give you the necessary information when creating your own framework.

http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1594

Hope this helps!